# How do I randomly generate a link to a file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services

I have a PDF file that I don't want to make publicly accessible from a URL on my site. As a (slight) layer of security, I'd like to email users a unique, randomly generated URL from which they can download the PDF, which I'll be storing on AWS or something similar.

I feel like I'm trapped in routes.rb prison, and I have no idea how to dynamically generate URLs, nor how to properly create random URLs, keep track of them, or link them up to files stored locally or on AWS.

Does anyone have any suggestions for approaching this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ahh yes I've done this before. I'm assuming you'll be using a file upload gem such as [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) and created some a model such as Pdf like:

```
class Pdf < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :pdf, storage: :s3
end
```

This sets up the model so you can upload a file to it and it will store it in AWS S3. You may not have it this way currently but **the idea is to have a database record where you can have a reference to the Pdf's URL and also a unique token your users will use to retrieve it without knowing the real URL.**

In the Pdf model you should have a token:string field and in a before_save filter in the model generate the unique token:

```
class Pdf < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'securerandom'
  has_attached_file :pdf, storage: :s3
  before_save :generate_unique_token

  private

  def generate_unique_token
    self.token ||= SecureRandom.hex
  end
end
```

And now you can set up a named route:

```
get '/hidden_pdf/:token', to: 'pdfs#get_hidden'
```

Add the get_hidden action to the Pdfs controller:

```
class PdfsController < ApplicationController
  def get_hidden
    pdf = Pdf.where(token: params[:token]).first

    if pdf
      # from the pdf model you have access to its real URL and you can send it directly
      data = open pdf.url
      send_data data.read, filename: pdf.pdf_file_name, type: "application/pdf", disposition: 'inline', stream: 'true', buffer_size: '4096'
    else
      # Not found logic here
    end
  end
end
```

Now you can just send your users a URL such as *myapp.com/pdfs/random-string-here* and when they go to it your app will find the record in the database by that token, pull the real URL of the PDF on AWS, read the data from it and force a download to the browser all without ever showing the real URL to the end user.

Answer (score 5):

How are you storing the PDF?  If you're using something like [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip), you can generate a temporary public URL to a private file quite easily:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :file

  # ...

  def file_url
    file.expiring_url(10)
  end

end
```

`file_url` will generate a 10-second-valid URL for that file. Then, in whatever controller is relevant, you can just have a "show" method for the file itself, which quickly redirects to the private url when accessed:

```
class AttachmentsController < ApplicationController

  # GET /whatever/attachments/:id
  def show
    redirect_to Attachment.find(params[:id]).file_url
  end

end
```

To achieve the "random" URL like you'll be sending, you'll need an extra step.  You could just generate a long hash using something like `SecureRandom.uuid`, and pass it in as a parameter, with a simple model of something like `AttachmentProxy`.

Something like:

```
class AttachmentProxy < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :attachment

  # has an attribute called 'key', indexed...

end
```

And in your controller for these:

```
class AttachmentProxyController < ApplicationController

  def show
    proxy = AttachmentProxy.find_by_key(params[:key])
    redirect_to proxy.attachment.file_url
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of different ways to approach this problem. Probably the simplest is just to create a database backed model that stores a reference to a pdf and a random id. Then the show action will be a link of the format `/obscured_pdf/asdkfjlkdafj1230-5324.pdf` or whatever random id you come up with. So for a basic example:

Controller

```
class ObscuredPdfsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @pdf = ObscuredPdf.find_by_obscured_id(params[:id]).pdf
    # render pdf, do whatever
  end
end
```

in routes.rb

```
resources :obscured_pdfs, only: :show
```

Obscured class

```
class ObscuredPdf < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pdf
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :obscured_id
end
```

Even better, add the `obscured_id` field to the pdf class, though this does not work as well if multiple people need different links to the same pdf. Personally my favorite option is to symmetrically encrypt the 'random' id based on the `user_id` and `pdf_id` so that you don't need to store it at all.