# Have a token/unique url in order to destroy resource

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to add following functionality to one of my models:
Once it's created, a token of some sort will be created and this token allows one to destroy the object e.g. http://localhost:3000/items/7AEaC6Nhq946.

Is there a gem or similiar that offers this functionality already?

Comment: This is literally < 20 lines of code. Nothing unusual too. Why don't you give it a try?

Comment: I think he needs some logic with tokens. E.g. a token can be used only once, validation for tokens, etc.

Comment: @AlexanderShlenchack: if token is stored on the model, problem of possible re-use goes away with the object (when it's destroyed). Unique index on the token column also wouldn't hurt.

Comment: You may find some ideas here  - [How do I randomly generate a link to a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847292/how-do-i-randomly-generate-a-link-to-a-file) - the idea can be extended to delete action

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a 'Tokenable' concern and include it in the models you want to:

In `app/models/concerns/tokenable.rb`

```
module Tokenable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_create :generate_token
  end

  protected

  def generate_token
    self.random_token = loop do
      random_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)
      break random_token unless self.class.exists?(random_token: random_token)
    end
  end
end
```

In your model:

`include Tokenable`

Be sure to add the `random_token` column in the database for the model where you include the concern.

Now in your controller you would do something like `Item.find_by(random_token: params[:random_token])` and perform the actions you wish to do with the object.

Comment: Thanks, I used your code plus mailing and routing and it works great! - Just thought there was a gem out there, that does exactly what I wanted.